# app.yaml : wildcard in URL with static_dir?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, frontend

My attempt at matching a regex as directory name in app.yaml doesn't work :

```
- url: /v1_.*
  static_dir: static/v1
  expiration: "364d"
```

Although [this official spec](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers) says regex syntax is supported. Is there a way to make this work ?

I.e. `/v1_2014-01-29/img/logo.png` should match the static file `/static/v1/img/logo.png`.

### Trivia

I use Google App Engine to serve a [Go](http://golang.org/) webapp.

I'd like to maximize browser cache longevity, minimize number of requests and still serve the fresh versions of my css/js/png, and I believe [revving filenames](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/) is a best practice to achieve this. Also as adding a variable querystring (`/v1/img/logo.png?2014-01-29`) might cause proxy and cache problems, I prefer to show a variable directory name (`/v1_2014-01-29/img/logo.png`), pointing to the same underlying server dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that whatever part of the URL that is beyond the match of the url definition (which matches from the start) is appended to the static_dir.

So the following handler should match `/v1_2014-01-29/img/logo.png` if the file path is `static/v1/img/logo.png` (tried with Python):

```
- url: /v1_(\d+-?)+
  static_dir: static/v1
```

Comment: You're right, the problem is certainly that `.*` also matches the empty string, and so `/v1_2014-01-29/img/logo.png` must actually be looking for `/static/v1/2014-01-29/img/logo.png`. Can you please explain how the `(\d+-?)+` works? I'll add another simple answer for future reference (no offense).

Comment: The `(\d+-?)+` part matches the date in the URL. Basically it is a (not quite equivalent) shortcut for `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`. I believe `v1_.*_` works too for a URL of the format `v1_YYYY-MM-DD_` because it looks for anything that starts with v1_, followed by anything in between, and then an underscore. I believe the remainder of the URL (`/img/logo.png`) is then appended to the static_dir to lookup the resource.

Answer (score 0):

After olivierdm's answer I changed my yaml into :

```
- url: /v1_.*_
  static_dir: static/v1
  expiration: "364d"
```

and my html templates to produce `/v1_2014-01-29_/img/logo.png`.

Basically, the extra arbitrary character underscore `_` forces `.*` to match `2014-01-29`, not the empty string.

Now every time I want the visitors to reload the static files, I just change the date in the tempating (I don't touch the app.yaml anymore). Also, any accidental request to an "outdated" URL will still succeed and serve the fresh resource.